Proving that the determinant of odd-dimensional Matrices is zero
Let $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ and the matrices $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_{2k+1}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A^2 B^2 = (AB)^2$. Show that $\det(AB - BA) = 0$.
Some ideas (Not sure that this is correct. Any help is appreciated):
The condition $ A^2 B^2 = (AB)^2 $ can be expanded as:
$
A^2 B^2 = ABAB.
$
Thus, we have:
$
A^2 B^2 - ABAB = 0.
$
This can be factored as:
$
A(A B^2 - B A B) = 0.
$
Hence, we obtain:
$
A(AB - BA)B = 0.
$
Let $ C = AB - BA $. From the equation $ A(AB - BA)B = 0 $, we deduce:
$
A C B = 0.
$
Thus, $ C $ has a non-trivial kernel.
Recall that for any $ X, Y \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C}) $, we have $ \text{Tr}(XY - YX) = 0 $. Applying this to $ A $ and $ B $, we get:
$
\text{Tr}(AB - BA) = \text{Tr}(C) = 0.
$
This implies that the sum of the eigenvalues of $ C $ is zero.
Since $ A $ and $ B $ are matrices of odd size $ (2k+1) \times (2k+1) $, the commutator matrix $ C = AB - BA $ must be singular. This follows from the following reasoning:
$ C = AB - BA $ is of odd size, hence it has an odd number of eigenvalues (counting multiplicities).
The trace of $C $, which is the sum of its eigenvalues, is zero: $ \text{Tr}(C) = 0 $.
For the sum of an odd number of eigenvalues to be zero, at least one of the eigenvalues must be zero.
Thus, $C $ has at least one eigenvalue equal to zero, meaning $ C $ is singular. Therefore:
$
\det(C) = 0.
$

An odd number $\ge3$ of nonzero numbers can easily sum to $0$, unless the kind of numbers allowed is suitably constrained.

@user8675309 how do I show that?

Let $A$ and $B$ be two linear operators on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. If $A(AB-BA)B=0$, then $\operatorname{range}\big((AB-BA)B\big)\subseteq\ker(A)$. Hence $\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}((AB-BA)B)\le\dim V$. So, if $AB-BA$ is nonsingular, we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)
\le\dim V
=\operatorname{rank}(AB-BA)
\le2\min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\}.
$$
Consequently, $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$ and $\dim V=2\operatorname{rank}(A)$.
In your case, however, $\dim V=2k+1$ is odd. Therefore $AB-BA$ must be singular.

To do this with less inequality manipulation:
$V=\mathbb F^n$ and suppose $\text{rank}\big(C\big)=n $, apply Frobenius Rank Inequality (or Sylvester) and negate and add $2n$ to each side to get
$n = 2n-\text{rank }C - 0\leq n-\text{rank }(AC)  + n - \text{rank }(CB)= \dim \ker A + \dim \ker B $
and since $C$ is invertible we know $ \ker A \cap \ker B =\big\{\mathbf 0\big\}$ and that implies $V= \ker A \oplus \ker B$ (why?)
Let $Z$  be an invertible matrix where the first $m$ columns form a basis for $\ker A$ and the rest a basis for $\ker B$.  And let $Y$ be an invertible matrix where the top $m$ rows form a basis for the Left Nullspace of $A$ and the rest form a basis for the Left Nullspace of $B$. Then
$n=\text{rank}\big(C\big) = \text{rank}\big(YCZ\big) = \text{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0_m & M \\ N &\mathbf 0_{n-m}\end{bmatrix}\right)$
observing if $m\neq n-m$ then either $M$ or $N$ is short and fat, making the matrix singular, so we conclude $2m =n$, i.e. $\text{rank}\big(C\big)=n \implies n$ is even.

suppose for contradiction that $\text{rank}\big(C\big)=2k +1$, with commutator $C=AB-BA$
1.) $\text{rank}\big(A\big)+\text{rank}\big(B\big) =\text{rank}\big(A\big)+\text{rank}\big(CB\big) \leq \text{rank}\big(ACB\big)+2k+1=2k+1$
by Sylvester's Rank Inequality
2.)$ACB = \mathbf 0\implies \big((BA)C\big)^2= \mathbf 0$ so another application of Sylvester's Rank Inequality and the fact that rank is an integer tells us
$\text{rank}\big(BA\big) =\text{rank}\big((BA)C\big)\leq k$
3.) $2k+1=\text{rank}\big(AB -BA\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(AB\big) +\text{rank}\big(-BA\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(AB\big) +k$
by sub-additivity of rank
Conclude:
$k+1\leq \text{rank}\big(AB\big) \leq \min\Big(\text{rank}\big(A\big),\text{rank}\big(B\big)\Big) \implies 2k + 2\leq \text{rank}\big(A\big)+\text{rank}\big(B\big)\leq 2k + 1 $
which is a contradiction.
